# Can Automator open a generated Google Doc?

Tags: automator, google-docs

I have an Automator that copies a Google Doc file from one folder into another one, and then rename it to something different (the name varies).

I'd like Automator to open the newly renamed file, but if I use "Open Finder  Items" right after, it opens the file before it's new name. Not sure how to solve that. Any ideas?

[image: Automator copy rename open]

Comment: Can you try adding a delay between the two actions or adding a notification in between just to see the behavior

Comment: I added a 5 sec delay, nothing. Still opens the original file. Here's a full image of the flow (in OP). It grabs a file from the folder "formats", copies it to a folder created earlier on the flow, renames it, adds a 5sec delay, and opens it. But no, it opens the original file from the "Formats" folder.

Comment: You shouldn't need a delay but using one isn't going to hurt either. What is in the Results pane of the Rename Finder Items: Replace Text action, does it return the original filename or the new filename?

Comment: I should have expanded the results for the renaming. And yes, it's definitively the new name. I'm thinking that I'm doing this operation on a Google Drive folder which syncs through their app, and there's definitively a delay on their end. I can also do away without opening the file, I was just trying to simplify a workflow for a team.